# Forward Declaration Error Driving Me Nuts

Tags: c++

Ok, I know this gets asked a lot by novice C++ users, because I've read a number of posts, but I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong even after reading the answers.  The code is long, so...be as forgiving as possible.

```
#include "dateType.h"

using namespace std;

void dateType::setDate(int y, int m, int d)
{
  y = year;
  m = month;
  d = day;
}

int dateType::getYear() const
{
  return year;
}

int dateType::getMonth() const
{
  return month; 
}

int dateType::getDay() const
{
  return day;
}

void dateType::getDate(int& year, int& month, int& day) const
{
  return (year, month, day);
}

bool dateType::operator==(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() == otherDate.getYear() && getMonth() == otherDate.getMonth()
      && d == otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator!=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return !(*this == otherDate);
}

bool dateType::operator<(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() < otherDate.getYear() || getMonth() < otherdate.getMonth() 
      || getDay() < otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator>(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() > otherDate.getYear() || getMonth() > otherDate.getMonth()
      || getDay() > otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator<=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return *this == otherDate || *this < otherDate;
}

bool dateType::operator>=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return *this == otherDate || *this > otherDate;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const dateType& d)
{
  out << dateType.getYear() << "-" << dateType.getMonth() << "-" << dateType.getDay();
  return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, dateType& d)
{
  //Variables
  int year,
      month,
      day;
  char dummy;

  in >> year >> dummy >> month >> dummy >> day;
  d.setDate(year, month, day);
  return in;
} 

dateType::dateType()
{
  year = 0000;
  month = 00;
  day = 00;
}

dateType::dateType(int y, int m, int d)
{
  setDate(y, m, d);
}
```

My .h file is:

```
#ifndef _DATETYPE_H_
#define _DATETYPE_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dateType
{
  public:
    /* Method:  Default contructor
     * Description:  Constructs a new dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  None
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object created and initialized to a date of
     * '0000-00-00' (format yyyy-mm-dd)
     * Method input:  Year (int), Month (int), Day (int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    dateType();

    /* Method:  Constructor
     * Description:  Constructs a new dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  None
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object create and initialized to a date of
     * format yyyy-mm-dd
     * Method input:  year (int), month (int), day (int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    dateType(int, int, int);

    /* Method:  setDate
     * Description:  Sets the date of a dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object has been initialized
     * Post-conditions:  new year, month and day has been set for dateType 
     * object
     * Method input:  year(int), month(int), day(int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    void setDate(int y, int m, int d);

    /* Method:  getYear
     * Descritpion:  Returns the year of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object year has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Year of the dateType (int)
     */
    int getYear() const;

    /* Method:  getMonth
     * Descritpion:  Returns the month of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object month has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Month of the dateType object (int)
     */
    int getMonth() const;

    /* Method:  getDay
     * Description:  Returns the day of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object month has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Day of the dateType object (int)
     */
    int getDay() const;

    /* Method:  getDate
     * Description:  Returns the year, month, and day of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object year, month and day has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  year (int), month(int), and day(int) of the dateType
     * object
     */
    void getDate() const;

  private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const dateType);
#endif
```

I'm still working on the .h file, but I tried to test just the initialization of the class in a main.cpp file.

```
dateType first_date(2014, 10, 31);
```

I get a number of errors, but among the first is: 
dateType.cpp:13:43: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class dateType’
 void dateType::setDate(int y, int m, int d)

Please tell me what I'm missing.

Thanks much.

Comment: In `setDate`: `y = year; m = month; d = day;` wat?

Comment: Oops, little oversight.  Thanks.

Comment: @Blackwell if you're using gcc or clang turn the warnings up to 11 with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++`, they can help you catch simple errors like this.

Comment: Your definitions and declarations don't match up, `getType` for instance, also missing `==` decorations.

Comment: The "error: invalid use of incomplete type " does not come from the code you posted. You've failed at all 3 of the **M**, **C**, and **V** parts of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected all errors check below files

to check it link http://ideone.com/nfdYo5

your .h file

```
#ifndef _DATETYPE_H_
#define _DATETYPE_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dateType
{
  public:
    /* Method:  Default contructor
     * Description:  Constructs a new dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  None
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object created and initialized to a date of
     * '0000-00-00' (format yyyy-mm-dd)
     * Method input:  Year (int), Month (int), Day (int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    dateType();

    /* Method:  Constructor
     * Description:  Constructs a new dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  None
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object create and initialized to a date of
     * format yyyy-mm-dd
     * Method input:  year (int), month (int), day (int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    dateType(int, int, int);

    /* Method:  setDate
     * Description:  Sets the date of a dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object has been initialized
     * Post-conditions:  new year, month and day has been set for dateType 
     * object
     * Method input:  year(int), month(int), day(int)
     * Method output:  None
     */
    void setDate(int y, int m, int d);

    /* Method:  getYear
     * Descritpion:  Returns the year of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object year has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Year of the dateType (int)
     */
    int getYear() const;

    /* Method:  getMonth
     * Descritpion:  Returns the month of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object month has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Month of the dateType object (int)
     */
    int getMonth() const;

    /* Method:  getDay
     * Description:  Returns the day of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object month has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  Day of the dateType object (int)
     */
    int getDay() const;

    /* Method:  getDate
     * Description:  Returns the year, month, and day of the dateType object
     * Pre-conditions:  dateType object exists
     * Post-conditions:  dateType object year, month and day has been returned
     * Method input:  None
     * Method output:  year (int), month(int), and day(int) of the dateType
     * object
     */
    dateType getDate() const;
    bool operator==(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    bool operator!=(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    bool operator<(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    bool operator>(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    bool operator<=(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    bool operator>=(const dateType& otherDate) const;
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out);
    istream& operator>>(istream& in);

  private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
#endif
```

your cpp file

```
#include "dateType.h"

void dateType::setDate(int y, int m, int d)
{
  year = y;
  month = m;
  day = d;
}

int dateType::getYear() const
{
  return year;
}

int dateType::getMonth() const
{
  return month; 
}

int dateType::getDay() const
{
  return day;
}

dateType dateType::getDate() const
{
 return dateType(year, month, day);
}

bool dateType::operator==(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() == otherDate.getYear() && getMonth() == otherDate.getMonth()
      && getDay() == otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator!=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return !(*this == otherDate);
}

bool dateType::operator<(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() < otherDate.getYear() || getMonth() < otherDate.getMonth() 
      || getDay() < otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator>(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return (getYear() > otherDate.getYear() || getMonth() > otherDate.getMonth()
      || getDay() > otherDate.getDay());
}

bool dateType::operator<=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return *this == otherDate || *this < otherDate;
}

bool dateType::operator>=(const dateType& otherDate) const
{
  return *this == otherDate || *this > otherDate;
}

ostream& dateType::operator<<(ostream& out)
{
  out << this->getYear() << "-" << this->getMonth() << "-" << this->getDay();
  return out;
}

istream& dateType::operator>>(istream& in)
{
  //Variables
  int year,
      month,
      day;
  char dummy;

  in >> year >> dummy >> month >> dummy >> day;
  this->setDate(year, month, day);
  return in;
} 

dateType::dateType()
{
  year = 0000;
  month = 00;
  day = 00;
}

dateType::dateType(int y, int m, int d)
{
  setDate(y, m, d);
}
```

copy and past and have fun

it was having lots of errors and typo... :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to return?.

```
void dateType::getDate(int& year, int& month, int& day) const
{
  return (year, month, day); <<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Please change this to

```
dateType dateType::getDate(int& year, int& month, int& day) 
{
  return dateType(year, month, day);
}
```

Comment: Fixed.  I wasn't sure how to return that one.  Should've seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Your setDate function is wrong . it should be

```
   void dateType::setDate(int y, int m, int d)
   {
      year = y;
      month = m;
      day = d;
   }
```

Also you dont need this declaration in .h

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const dateType);
```